# Testing vehicle by simultaneously applying brakes and accelerator

Tags: brakes

I was told by a former stock car driver that he always tests vehicles he is thinking of buying by simultaneously applying the brakes and the accelerator to make sure the wheels will spin.  As I understand it, this procedure supposedly checks engine power and (automatic) transmission torque conversion.  What do  professional mechanics think of this?

Comment: What happens if something breaks while you are doing something many people would consider abusive?

Comment: I'm not a professional mechanic, but I will opine that abusing a vehicle or using it in a fashion not intended is a bad idea. Did they mention how EXACTLY this procedure "checks engine power and (automatic) transmission torque conversion?" How is a qualitative or quantitative comparison achieved? This is foolishness IMO.

Comment: Utter nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a antiquated good-ol-boy kind of test...  Maybe this is valid on an '86 Z28 Camaro, but with ABS and traction control and all the other safety improvements on modern cars, this isn't something you should do.  There are cars now that just ignore the throttle when the brake is pressed!

Heck, even if you are buying an older car, I wouldn't do this on a car that I didn't own.  If you came to look at my car and pulled that, you'd be asked to leave immediately.  When you're test driving someone else's car, don't do anything out of the ordinary.  No clutch drops, no locking up the brakes (heavy braking, sure, but within reason), no wide open throttle launches...  Respect the car.